# Petsc Mat object in class

Tags: petsc, mpi, oop

[Relatively new to Petsc] I am writing an object oriented project and my idea is to have parallel objects when the user constructs the object with MPI arguments. So have member data Mat and fill/assembly it in the constructor. Though I am struggling doing this correctly so that's my first question (see below the code. Please let me know if you need a minimal working example to debug). My second general question is how would you go about doing this? How would you interface with this object without breaking encapsulation and having general good practices?

Here is an example of what I am thinking, first the hpp file

```cpp
   class Toperator {
   public:
     /// Toperator: $T = \Del^2 + \frac{l(l+1)}{2x^2}$
     Toperator(std::shared_ptr<FEMDVR> a_radial_grid, const int &a_lmax_times_2);
  
     Toperator(const PetscMPIInt &a_numprocs, const PetscMPIInt &id,
               std::shared_ptr<FEMDVR> a_radial_grid, const int &a_lmax_times_2);
  
     /// Destructor
     ~Toperator();
  
     /// Needed to destroy the TXX Petsc Matrix
     void destroyTXXPetscMatrix();
  
     /// Needed to destroy the TIXX Petsc Matrix
     void destroyTIXXPetscMatrix();
  
     /// Returns the TXX Petsc Matrix, i.e. return type Mat
     Mat getTXXPetscMat();
  
     /// Returns the TIXX Petsc Matrix, i.e. return type Mat
     Mat getTIXXPetscMat();
  
     /// Getter for the T operator in the DVR representation.
     std::complex<double> getTXX(int index) const;
  
     /// Getter for the inverse of the T operator in the DVR representation.
     /// Used in the poison solution for $\frac{1}{|r_1-r_2|}.
     std::complex<double> getTIXX(int index) const;
  
   private:
     std::unique_ptr<std::complex<double>[]> m_dvr_rep, m_inverse_dvr_rep;
     Mat m_TXX, m_TIXX;
   };
```

One thing to note, I would like to create a custom destructor that destroys the Petsc Mat objects but not sure how to do that. In general, how would you interface with this Mat object in a class? I am just returning the whole Mat but not sure if this works. Though, I would love to hear better designs!

Now the parallel constructor implementation (I am not sure about the initialization of Mat in the member list).

```cpp
Toperator::Toperator(const PetscMPIInt &a_numprocs, const PetscMPIInt &id,
                     std::shared_ptr<FEMDVR> a_radial_grid,
                     const int &a_lmax_times_2)
    : m_dvr_rep(std::unique_ptr<std::complex<double>[]>(
          new std::complex<double>[a_radial_grid->getNbas() *
                                   a_radial_grid->getNbas() *
                                   a_lmax_times_2]())),
      m_inverse_dvr_rep(std::unique_ptr<std::complex<double>[]>(
          new std::complex<double>[a_radial_grid->getNbas() *
                                   a_radial_grid->getNbas() *
                                   a_lmax_times_2]())), m_TXX(nullptr), m_TIXX(nullptr) {
  PetscErrorCode ierr;
  PetscInt nbas = a_radial_grid->getNbas();
  ierr = MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &m_TXX);
  ierr = MatSetSizes(m_TXX, PETSC_DECIDE, PETSC_DECIDE, a_lmax_times_2,
                     nbas * nbas);
  ierr = MatSetFromOptions(m_TXX);
  ierr = MatSetUp(m_TXX);

  int start, end;
  MatGetOwnershipRange(m_TXX, &start, &end);

  for (int l = start; l < end; ++l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nbas; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < nbas; ++j) {
        if (i == j) {
          int index = i * nbas + j;
          PetscScalar tmp_TXX = a_radial_grid->getLaplacian(i * nbas + j) +
                                (std::complex<double>)(l * (l + 1)) /
                                    pow(a_radial_grid->getPoint(j), 2);
          /* MatSetValue(m_TXX, l, index, tmp_TXX, ADD_VALUES); */
          MatSetValues(m_TXX, 1, &l, 1, &index, &tmp_TXX, INSERT_VALUES);
        } else {
          int index = i * nbas + j;
          PetscScalar tmp_TXX = a_radial_grid->getLaplacian(i * nbas + j);
          /* MatSetValue(m_TXX, l, index, tmp_TXX, ADD_VALUES); */
          MatSetValues(m_TXX, 1, &l, 1, &index, &tmp_TXX, INSERT_VALUES);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  MatAssemblyBegin(m_TXX, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
  MatAssemblyEnd(m_TXX, MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
}

Toperator::~Toperator() {}

void Toperator::destroyTXXPetscMatrix() { MatDestroy(&m_TXX); }

void Toperator::destroyTIXXPetscMatrix() { MatDestroy(&m_TIXX); }

Mat Toperator::getTXXPetscMat() { return m_TXX; }

Mat Toperator::getTIXXPetscMat() { return m_TIXX; }

std::complex<double> Toperator::getTXX(int index) const {
  return m_dvr_rep[index];
}

std::complex<double> Toperator::getTIXX(int index) const {
  return m_inverse_dvr_rep[index];
}
```

The MatSetValues does't work right. Here is the output. Looks like just iterations and not my laplacian values.

```bash
 local_row 19 local_column 8
Mat Object: 2 MPI processes
  type: mpiaij
row 0: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 1: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 2: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 3: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 4: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 5: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 6: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 7: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 8: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 9: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 10: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 11: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 12: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 13: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 14: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 15: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 16: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 17: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
row 18: (0, 1.)  (1, 0.)  (2, 0.)  (3, 0.)  (4, 0.)  (5, 0.)  (6, 0.)  (7, 0.)
```

Here is the working sequential code

```cpp
  int nbas = a_radial_grid->getNbas();
  for (int l = 0; l < a_lmax_times_2; ++l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nbas; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < nbas; ++j) {
        if (i == j) {
          m_dvr_rep[l * nbas * nbas + i * nbas + j] =
              a_radial_grid->getLaplacian(i * nbas + j) +
              (std::complex<double>)(l * (l + 1)) /
                  pow(a_radial_grid->getPoint(j), 2);
        } else {
          m_dvr_rep[l * nbas * nbas + i * nbas + j] =
              a_radial_grid->getLaplacian(i * nbas + j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In this code snippet, m_dvr_rep is the Petsc Mat I am trying to create in Parallel. As you can see, I am striding across three loops so I am not sure how to map this structure on to Mat but you can see my attempt above. When I view the Matrix it only has iterations in it so I think I am doing something silly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an example, take a look at the `MatrixBase` class here:
https://github.com/dealii/dealii/blob/master/include/deal.II/lac/petsc_matrix_base.h
https://github.com/dealii/dealii/blob/master/source/lac/petsc_matrix_base.cc

Comment: Take a look at the tests in the `tests/petsc/` directory of that project. These are going to be the most to-the-point examples.

Comment: @zstreet Thanks for the kind words -- pretty much two decades of my academic life have gone into this :-)

Comment: It shows!  And this will help accelerate my growth as well!

Comment: @zstreet Well, thanks again the for the additional kind words :-)

Comment: How would you map my serial three loop construction of the T matrix to a parallel PETSc version?  The serial version is correct so just check that out.  The PETSc version is my flawed attempt...

Comment: Or would a PETSc vector be more appropriate and just insert with the stride pattern I show above ```[ l*nbas*nbas + i*nbas + j ]``` ?  I am not sure how to do the domain decomposition

Comment: Either way works. Define a way where each element of the matrix or vector is written to by exactly one processor, then run that loop and at the end call `VecAssembleBegin/End` or `MatAssembleBegin/End` to exchange the entries written to from the processors that did the writing to the processors that own the entries written to. After that, every processor knows about the values in those elements it owns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the MatDestroy in your destructor.
2. Your logic for setting elements is completely wrong. The easiest solution is:

// stuff

```
for ( .... i .... )
   for ( ... j ... )
      for ( .... l ... )
         globalnumber = l * nbas * nbas + i * nbas + j
         if ( globalnumber>=low && globalnumber<high ) 
            MatSetValue
```

Comment: I initially tried putting the call to MatDestroy in the destructor but it was giving errors.  Can you give me an example?  I'll try again...  I am not following your code snippet, sorry.  Can you expand with the actual MatSetValues full call?  Also I am trying to use MatSetValues so each row and not MatSetValue.  Note, my first time ever using these!

Comment: also, do you have any recommendations for design?  For example, would you create a getter that returns Mat like I am showing?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: The MatSetValue call is not the point. Your treatment of indices and ownership is.

Comment: Yes I know I am not doing it correctly.  Though your snippet isn't clear to me, sorry.  My example is over 3 loops l, i, and j.  Should I assume this is inside the first l loop?  How do you stride appropriately for three loops? Is your ```low high``` variables my ```start end``` that I get from the Ownership call?

Comment: What are your three loops? The i,j coordinates in your domain and what?

Comment: Please refer to my code snippets I posted.  The last version is the serial version I want to use Petsc to parallelize.  The three loop variables are l, i, and then j.  The first loop is over the number of angular momentum and the next two are over number of basis functions. This code is using partial wave expansion, if that helps clarify the logic.

Comment: Ok, I spelled it out. What I called `global_number` is the stuff that you spelled out as

    
    l * nbas * nbas + i * nbas + j

That's your global matrix row index. You need to test on that.